# ASP.net form's designer file deleted.

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and mistakenly my aspx.cs.designer.cs file gets deleted and now it is giving compile time error. How to regenerate deleted file?

Comment: Sorry, but only a backup or manually rebuilding it

Comment: Oh no! but its a auto generated file??

Comment: Copy the aspx and cs code to nodepad, delete both aspx and cs file, Add new form with the same name, copy the ascx and cs code back from notepad. Should now be fine

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I got another simple way by right clicking on .aspx file and choosen 'Convert to web Application'. This has regenerated [.designer.cs] file. I forgot to mention that I am using Visual Studio 2010 this has option to regenerate file. Thanks!!